# Python 3: self variable in init can't be changed?

Tags: python

Im programing a game for school right now. Its going pretty well so far, so Im now trying to implement an undo option after each players turn.

1. My board is a 7x7 matrix and is defined in __ init __ as self.board.
2. The board will be manipulated by each players turn.
3. Besides I have self.saved_states = [] defined in __ init __. This list is supposed to store copies of every state of the game after every players turn.

So far I have a method that actually saves state into the list mentioned in 3.

```
def save_state(self):
    copied_board = copy.copy(self.board)
    self.saved_states.append(copied_board)
```

I tested this and this seems to work. The problem is somewhere else.

So I will get input from user, if he inputs 'u' instead of actual valid game input I want to do the following:

```
if input == 'u':
    print('Undoing last turn!')
    self.board = self.saved_states.pop()
    self.player_2()
```

I just want to change the current state of the game to the previous one and have player 2 take their turn (again).

Whats the problem here? Every time each player take its turn Im manipulating elements of the board too. Why can't I just replace the whole board with a previous one? I don't see the difference here.

Thanks for any help or idea!

Comment: Provide the error you get and more of your code, where is the `if...` located in your program, this might be a scope issue.

Comment: There is no way to verify anything here, as you left out crucial bits of information. My best bet for now is that the last saved state is exactly equal to the current board and you do not want the last saved state, but the previous one..

Comment: voiDnyx: I won't get an Error. Its printing Undoing last turn! and then just lets player_2 continue. But the board will be the same. The if statement is located in the self.players_turn() method. The player can either input a valid input like 4x5, so a stone will be placed on 4x5, or undo the previous turn.

Uvar: what information are missing. Sorry Im new to this, I don't really know which information are important to find the error.

Comment: If this is a UI application, did you also remember to redraw the board when undoing a step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a wild guess: If your `self.board` is "a 7x7 matrix", it's probably a list of lists, so you should use `copy.deepcopy` to copy the board. Otherwise, the *inner* lists will still be the same, and as you modify the current board, you also modify all the "copies".

```
def save_state(self):
    copied_board = copy.deepcopy(self.board)
    self.saved_states.append(copied_board)
```

Alternatively, instead of storing the board layouts for each turn, store the moves performed by the players and replay the game accordingly.

Comment: Right guess, lists in a list. And yes I will try deepcopy. I have used deep copy before but didn't really think of it here. Thx. will be back in a sec.

Comment: Wont work. I don't think copying is the problem. I tested that part. Yes I think storing the players turn works too but I really want to stick to this solution for now :D

Comment: @MarcelB I you have a list of lists, then `copy` must have been a problem, but there might be others. How did you test that copying works? Maybe you have another reference to the board that is used in some places instead of using `self.board` directly? I don't see how the assignment should not work.

Comment: I found the issue. It was an issue of when I used save_state. I didn't have it placed correctly so at times it would save to often so it wouldn't give me the previous state, but the current state again. But I can't really tell you what the problem was without you having the whole code. Thank you guys for your help anyways! And thx Tobi for the deepcopy issue